# Наблюдатель за контактами телефонной книги

Tags: content, android, observer

Добрый день, друзья!

В своем приложении необходимо мониторить контакты телефонной книги - появление новых и удаление. Для этого использую ContentObserver. У данного класа есть интерфейс с методом  `public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri)`.

Если удаляю или добавляю контакт, то код в этом методе выполняется.

Но как мне узнать, какой именно контакт добавился или удалился?
Придется писать свой код поиска? либо эту информацию где-то можно вытянуть?

Comment: А какой uri приходит?

Comment: content://com.android.contacts